# PyCharm node.js server to use certain npm version when using nvm

Tags: npm, pycharm, nvm

How to convince PyCharm's Run/debug Configuration for a Node Server to use a certain npm version when using nvm?

Despite setting the node interpreter to ~/.nvm/versions/node/v12.14.1/
and installing a certain npm version for that node version, it holds on to some other version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the npm version mix-up by setting PATH in the environment variables of the Run/Debug Configuration to the correct node version. In my case:

`/Users/usr/.nvm/versions/node/v12.14.1/bin`

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer, it helped me from losing all my hair